# Change . to , decimal number userform entry on vba

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, userform

I have a create a Userform VBA EXCEL asking an Exchange Rare value, the entry comes (for example) 1.25, but Excel don't recognized as number. So as soon as I tried a calculation on new cell, the error comes as #VALUE!"
How can I change this "Text" into Value. My code below.

```
Private Sub Exchange_Rate_Exit(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    If Not IsNumeric(Exchange_Rate.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Only DECIMAL NUMBER VALUES allowed"
        Cancel = True
    End If
    
    Sheets("Menu").Range("EXC_RAT") = Exchange_Rate

End Sub
```

Comment: `IsNumeric` will accept "1.25", so something else/more must be going on.

Comment: @Gustav IsNumeric results are Locale dependent. On my setup, IsNumeric("1.25") is false while IsNumeric("1,25") is true.

Comment: @VincentG: Here both "1,25" and "1.25" validates having comma as the decimal separator.